# array undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I've a array which is the following;

```
var imgArray = (function() {
    var kleuren = ["harten", "klaveren", "koeken", "schoppen"];
    var result = [];

    for(var k = 0; k != kleuren.length; k++) {
        for(var n = 1; n <= 13; ++n) {
            result.push("images/" + kleuren[k] + "/" + kleuren[k] + n.toString() + ".png");
        }
    }
})();
```

And this is where I call my function/Array:

```
if(counter <= 5) {
    var arrayIndex = computeIndex(type, face);
    $('#cardplace' + counter).css("background-image", "url('" + imgArray[arrayIndex] + "')");
    ++counter;
} else {
    alert("Je hebt te veel kaarten genomen...");
    document.reload();
}
```

But my Nightly give the Error that imgArray is undefined,
where did i go wrong?

Comment: The IIFE returns undefined, as that is what a function returns as default.

Comment: Your function creates an array in `result`, but never actually returns it, so `imgArray` remains `undefined`

Comment: -1 : it's just about forgetting return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

```
return result;
```

at the end of your function.

Comment: oh my, i was so focused on other things, damn, thank alot guys !